# Designer Based String Keys for Variables, Faster algorithms or patterns to look at

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to design a text area that allows for designers to to use keys '{variableName}' within an editor window. I currently have an implementation that traverses the FieldInfo of the sent class to retrieve the values. Due to this using reflection it is quite slow (Relatively).

QUESTION: Does anyone know of a better method or options that allow the same options, functionality, and flexibility. This could be a different implementation or pattern.

This works as intended with the code below, just inefficient:

```
    public static class FormattedString
    {
        
        public static string GetFormattedString(string baseString, object obj)
        {
            if (!baseString.Contains('{'))
                return baseString;

            string formattedString = "";

            foreach (var split in baseString.Split('{'))
            {
                if (!split.Contains('}'))
                {
                    formattedString += split;
                }
                else
                {
                    int index = split.IndexOf('}');
                    formattedString += GetFieldValue(split.Substring(0, index), obj);

                    if (index < split.Length)
                        formattedString += split.Substring(index + 1);
                }
            }
            return formattedString;
        }

        public static string GetFieldValue(string name, object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return obj.GetType().GetField(name).GetValue(obj).ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "{Unable to find: "+ name+"}" ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably could do something with regex, but, its not something ive looked into

Comment: a bit hard to imagine how exactly this is being used / what its purpose is - could you add more context to convert this into a [mcve] ... but yeah I don't think there is something that provides `the same options, functionality, and flexibility` of Reflection without being Reflection ...

Comment: In Unity, our designers work in custom editors, so we are trying to determine a way that allows the programmers to add and remove options for Tooltips. The functions above allow for the designers to write "Deals {maxDamage} to the target" with {maxDamage} being replaced with the corresponding integer. 

The programmers then setup a drawer for the object to provide a list of Enums as a drop down for each of the available variables. 

The easiest way we thought of was a private 'object[]' that could be sent to a String.Format(), this would require more maintenance than just adding to an Enum

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out a process to accomplish the desired task inside and outside runtime using delegation and a dictionary.

**Inside Runtime:** Registered the object by delegating the ToString() of an object within the dictionary.

**Outside Runtime:** Using Unity's OnValidate() allowed for the delegation to be added / updated during inspector validation.

Combined these options allowed for a simple way for designers to create interpolated strings at runtime with little to no penalty.

Link to Source: https://github.com/JBWD/Unity-Tooltip-FormattedText